# Google Cloud as server for node.js

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to create a node.js with express application that can host multiple clients with different domain names.

I have never created such application, so my question is:

> If I have a project on my computer and want google (or some other hosting) to run my node application, how do I do it? Do I need to zip the whole project, and transfer it to the host? If not, how do Google know the front-end and back-end code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to deploy your code, [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) is the best option for you.

You can deploy your code there, and Google will manage how many instances will you need. For NodeJS, you can see a quickstart that will show you how to start [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/quickstart). You can deploy different [services](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/an-overview-of-app-engine#services_versions_and_instances) and map those services with different [domain names](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/mapping-custom-domains).

There are examples on App Engine if you are using [Express](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-expressjs-on-google-app-engine), and a [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/tutorial-app) that will show you how to organize your front-end and back-end in App Engine.